# Проблема с пониманием функции провеки регекспа

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, функции

Проблема в том, что у меня ничего не выводит.
И я плохо понимаю, как работает функция.

Вызов функции:

```
verify(/.../,
       ["red platypus", "wobbling nest"],
       ["earth bed", "learning ape", "BEET"]);
```

Готовый рег експ:

```
 verify(/\b[^\We]+\b/i,
       ["red platypus", "wobbling nest"],
       ["earth bed", "learning ape", "BEET"]);
```

Код функции:

```
function verify(regexp, yes, no) {
  // Ignore unfinished exercises
  if (regexp.source == "...") return;
  for (let str of yes) if (!regexp.test(str)) {
    console.log(`Failure to match '${str}'`);
  }
  for (let str of no) if (regexp.test(str)) {
    console.log(`Unexpected match for '${str}'`);
  }
}
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, нет, скорее упражнение в том, чтобы написать regexp, который для элементов первого массива будет возвращать `true`, и для элементов второго - `false`

Comment: Ничего не выводит, потому что все совпадения в порядке, в  `["red platypus", "wobbling nest"]` есть совпадение, а в `["earth bed", "learning ape", "BEET"]` нет, см. https://regex101.com/r/K680XH/1

Comment: @Alexander_Sky, логи выводятся только в случае ошибок, судя по всему сейчас ошибок нет.

Comment: меня смущает то, что \W означает большую букву, а такой комбинации (большая + маленькая буква e, я не нахожу)

Comment: \W означает не большую букву, а любой символ, не входящий в класс [a-zA-Z0-9_].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну прочитайте [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

> Метод test() выполняет поиск сопоставления регулярного выражения
> указанной строке. Возвращает true или false.

В вашем случае

```
for (let str of yes) if (!regexp.test(str)) ...
//Выполнить для каждого str из массива yes. Если строка str не проходит проверку regexp тогда .....
```

Comment: а почему в готовом регекспе оно мне не выводит ни один из консоль логов?

Comment: @Alexander_Sky Потому что всё в порядке